# Aggregate Function / Group By Clause

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Having some minor issues with my query. I am trying just to get sums for a project. I know I am probably missing something super simple but I am getting caught up. If someone could take a look and give me a suggestion on how I can figure this out.

```
select
    (select count(distinct(o1.orderno)) 
        from mck_hvs.orderheader o1 with(nolock)
        where o1.orderno = od.orderno and o1.refrigerate = 'Y' 
         ) as TotalColdOrders,

    (select count(distinct(o2.orderno))
        from mck_hvs.orderdetails o2 with(nolock)
        where o2.orderno = od.orderno and o2.drugclass 
        not in ('null', 'Rx')
        ) as ControlledOrders,

    (select count(distinct(o3.orderno)) 
        from mck_hvs.orderheader o3 with(nolock)
        where o3.orderno = od.orderno and o3.pucksideinorder = 'Y' and
        o3.totesideinorder = 'N' and o3.numitems > 4 
        ) as RobotOrders,

    (select count(distinct(o4.orderno)) 
        from mck_hvs.orderheader o4 with(nolock) 
        where o4.orderno = od.orderno and o4.pucksideinorder = 'Y' and
        o4.totesideinorder = 'Y' 
        ) as ComboOrders,

    (select count(distinct(o5.rxnum))
        from mck_hvs.orderdetails o5 with(nolock)
        where o5.refrigerate = 'Y' 
        ) as TotalColdScripts,

    (select count(distinct(o6.rxnum))
        from mck_hvs.orderdetails o6 with(nolock)
        where o6.orderno = od.orderno and o6.drugclass 
        not in ('null', 'RX')
        ) as ControlledScripts,

    (select sum(o7.numscripts)
        from mck_hvs.orderheader o7 with(nolock)
        where o7.orderno = od.orderno and o7.pucksideinorder = 'Y' and
        o7.totesideinorder = 'N' and o7.numitems > 4 
        ) as RobotScripts,

    (select sum(o8.numscripts) 
        from mck_hvs.orderheader o8 with(nolock) 
        where o8.orderno = od.orderno and o8.pucksideinorder = 'Y' and
        o8.totesideinorder = 'Y' 
        ) as ComboOrderScripts,

    count(distinct(od.orderno)) as TotalOrders,
    count(distinct(od.rxnum)) as TotalScripts 
from
    mck_hvs.orderdetails od with( nolock )
```

Comment: a Left join ON ORDERHEADER and ORDERDETAILS and apply CASE or IIF in the SELECT over GROUP BY

Comment: What is your problem? Wrong result or SQL Error? What is expected result or error message?

Comment: I am gett the "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'Mck_hvs.orderdetails.orderno" is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I am trying to get just totals of each sub query so I can match them to the TotalOrders and TotalScripts

Comment: Do you need an aggregation by each OrderNo? Or across all orders?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
SELECT
    od.orderno,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN oh.refrigerate = 'Y' THEN od.orderno END
    ) AS totalcoldorders,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN od.drugclass NOT IN ('null', 'Rx') THEN od.orderno END
    ) AS controlledorders,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE 
            WHEN oh.pucksideinorder = 'Y' 
                AND oh.totesideinorder = 'N' AND oh.numitems > 4 
            THEN od.orderno
        END 
    ) AS robotorders,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE 
            WHEN oh.pucksideinorder = 'Y' AND oh.totesideinorder = 'Y'
            THEN oh.orderno
        END
    ) AS comboorders,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN od.refrigerate = 'Y' THEN od.rxnum END 
    ) AS totalcoldscripts,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 
        CASE WHEN od.drugclass NOT IN ('null', 'RX') THEN od.rxnum END 
    ) AS controlledscripts,
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN oh.pucksideinorder = 'Y' 
                AND oh.totesideinorder = 'N' AND oh.numitems > 4 
            THEN oh.numscripts
         END
    ) AS robotscripts,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN oh.pucksideinorder = 'Y' AND oh.totesideinorder = 'Y' 
            THEN oh.numscripts
         END 
    ) AS comboorderscripts,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT orderno)
        FROM mck_hvs.orderdetails WITH (nolock) 
    ) AS totalorders,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT rxnum)
        FROM mck_hvs.orderdetails WITH (nolock) 
    ) AS totalscripts
FROM mck_hvs.orderdetails od WITH (nolock) 
LEFT JOIN mck_hvs.orderheader oh WITH (nolock) 
ON oh.orderno = od.orderno 
GROUP BY od.orderno
ORDER BY od.orderno;
```